# IPC Server handler / File does not exist, running hadoop in singularity container

Tags: hadoop, singularity-container

I don't have any experience with hadoop and am running into issues while attempting to run a [singularity container](https://github.com/HippocampusGirl/ImputationProtocol?tab=readme-ov-file) that uses it - it seems like it's not really getting started and i'm trying to figure out why.  After sifting through all the output, this seems to be the first indication of the problem:

```
2024-03-10 17:25:12 INFO  Server:3102 - IPC Server handler 7 on default port 51139, call Call#41 Retry#0 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.complete from localhost:60086 / 127.0.0.1:60086: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/ark19/cloudgene-cli/job-20240310-170017/temp/outputimputation/18/temp/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1710089589002_0004_m_000000_0/part-m-00000 (inode 16888) [Lease.  Holder: DFSClient_attempt_1710089589002_0004_m_000000_0_-1772981706_1, pending creates: 1]
```

Since I have very little understanding of how hadoop works, I'm not even sure where to start troubleshooting, and the first thing that I observe is that i don't even see a `/user` dir:

```
Singularity> ls /
anaconda-post.log  bin  data  dev  environment  etc  home  hpc  lib  lib64  localdata  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  singularity  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

I am working on my institution's computer cluster running AlmaLinux 9.3 & slurm (and running from inside the container):

```
srun -c 32 --x11 --mem=128G --pty bash -i
singularity shell --hostname localhost --bind ${workingDirectory}:/data --bind ${containerDirectory}/imputation-protocol-latest.sif
```

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, or need to further troubleshoot my configuration.  I thought I was potentially on to something when I discovered this comment in `hadoop/config/hdfs-site.xml`:

```
Immediately exit safemode as soon as one DataNode checks in. On a multi-node cluster, these configurations must be removed.
```

But lines following that comment didn't change anything.

Happy to provide further information on my set up but don't yet know what is most relevant.  Thanks!